# MySQL stored procedure - displaying an input parameter as a column alias

Tags: mysql

I'm building what's effectively a user cross tab report in a stored procedure, 11 columns or so, from temp tables that the SP creates.  There are two input parameters that I would like to display, concatenated, as the column alias for the first column, so the user can see what the selection criteria were when subsequently looking at the output.  At the moment I can't even get one of the input parameters to display.

I have searched extensively on this, and can't seem to figure out a way of doing it.  I found a similar issue on a post related to T-Sql, it seems the answer is "dynamic SQL" but I don't know if that applies for MySQL, or if it's even applicable to my problem.

My input parameters in my SP look like this:

`` CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Cyze_reportV2`(IN Select_shopper_ID int(11) , Select_scenario varchar(45)) ``

To give you the idea, one of my several failed attempts at assigning the input parameters to the first column alias looks like this:

`select aa.itemid as concat(Select_shopper_ID, Select_scenario)`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: *it seems the answer is "dynamic SQL" but I don't know if that applies for MySQL* True. Only prepared statement may solve. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

Comment: Thank you Akina, I will try this solution

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has the concept of dynamic sql.

Try using Prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, I did a bit of reading on prepared statements, it looks like they might be of more benefit for my reporting than just this one issue.  I'll do some testing and will post back here if/when I have a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to @Ganesh Chandrasekaran who steered me in the right direction, I have managed to solve this using dynamic SQL in a stored procedure.  To summarise the problem, I'm trying to link transactions to an item master table and display them in a cross tab report, with the column name for the items in the first column being the concatenated selection criteria the user entered for the report.

The solution is to use dynamic SQL to create a new temporary table with the desired column name each time the stored procedure is run, and join to that table in the query that generates the report.

I could not find any simple examples of how to construct this, so I put together the following with explanatory comments, which I hope will help others with the same problem.  You will need to remove the two lines of comment in the dynamic SQL in order for this to run.  There are probably other ways of constructing this, but it works and runs fairly fast.

```
-- A simple example of a stored procedure with input parameters used in dynamic SQL to create a variable column name
delimiter // 
CREATE PROCEDURE dynamic(IN scenario CHAR(64), IN shopper char(64))
BEGIN
drop table if exists `itemdynamic`;
-- This is where the SP input parameters are added as variables for the dynamic SQL
    set @sc = scenario;
    set @sh = shopper;
-- defining the dynamic SQL
    SET @s = CONCAT('
--  dynamic SQL starts here, which creates the table with the column name based on the SP input parameters
    CREATE TABLE `itemdynamic` (
  `' ,@sc, '' ,@sh, '` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`' ,@sc, '' ,@sh, '`));
  -- dynamic SQL ends here  
    ')
  ;
    --  This part runs the dynamic SQL:
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    --  A second dynamic SQL to populate the temporary item table from the permanent item table.
    SET @ss = CONCAT('

insert into itemdynamic (`' ,@sc, '' ,@sh, '`)
  SELECT
  `itemname` from `item`;

    ')
  ;

    PREPARE sstmt FROM @ss;
    EXECUTE sstmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE sstmt;
END
//
delimiter ;
--  We now have a temporary table created the same as the permanent table, but with the desired column
-- name based on the stored procedure input parameters.
```